# Is $\,x(-t+1)\,$ a time-invariant system?

Tags: solution-verification, signal-processing

Suppose we have $\,y(t) = x(-t+1)\,.$
I want to prove that $\,y(t)\,$ is time-invariant.

Reading from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-invariant_system)

> More generally the relationship between the input and the output is $\,y(t) = f\big(x(t),t\big)$ ,
>
> and its variation with time is
>
> $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{dx}{dt}$
>
> For time invariant systems, the system properties remain constant with time,
> $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$.

In my case $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$ is true so the system should be time invariant. Is this correct ? And if so, can I use the above to always check if a system is time-invariant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest test for time invariance is that if

$$ x(t) \Rightarrow y(t)$$

then
$$ x(t+d) \Rightarrow y(t+d) $$

Which simply means "a given time shift of the input signal results in the same time shift of the output signal".

So given the system

$$ y(t) = x(-t+1) $$

we want to check if shifting the input by some arbitrary amount $d$ results in the output being shifted by that same amount $d$:
$$y(t+d)\stackrel{?}{=} x(-t+1+d)$$

So working through the algebra we find:

$$\begin{align*}x(\left[-t+1\right]+d) &= x(-[t-d]+1)\\
&= y(t-d)\\
&\ne  y(t+d)\\
\end{align*}$$

and we can conclude the system is not time-invariant.

In fact shifting the input in one direction, shifts the output in the opposite direction.  This system is very dependent on the timing of the input relative to time $t=0$, since the system reverses the time axis in the output.

Comment: What does $x(t) \implies y(t)$ mean here?

Comment: @TC159 Sorry I forgot that I was on a math site and abused notation.  The arrow was just meant to convey that a system input of $x(t)$ results in a system output of $y(t)$.